# Radeon HD 7500M/7600M drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, radeon, amd-graphics

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop which has AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M dedicated GPU. I observed that driver 'radeon' is installed but only Intel Graphics are being used. I'm a noob and finding trouble in activating AMD GPU. AMD has AMDGPU-PRO drivers for 16.04 but not available for 20.04. Wanted to reach out to you all for help. Below are my observations which might help you to assist me.
I have checked the additional drivers page first but it had no drivers mentioned in it.
[image]

```
glxinfo -B
```

[image: 'glxinfo -B' instruction gives the following result]

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

[image: sudo lshw -c video result]

```
lsmod | grep radeon
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Maybe reinstalling driver:
[https://www.amd.com/en/support](https://www.amd.com/en/support)
and reading installation notes: [https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf](https://drivers.amd.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf) [Graphics --> AMD Radeon HD --> AMD Radeon HD 7000 series --> AMD Radeon HD 7510M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPIHh.png)